# Struts 1.3 Session Management

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts

I am using the session object to store the logged in user id in `signUpAction.java`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if(login>0&&candy>0){                
    session.setAttribute("username", val.getUsername());
    result = "success";    
}
```

then i forward the user to a jsp page corresponding to his/her id.

```
User name is `<bean:write name="signUp" property="username"/>`
```

The problem is that when the user clicks the back button, he/she logs back out(without clicking any logout button). I want a session to be maintained until the user clicks on the logout button. And how do i check whether the user is logged in on every page?
I am using Struts 1.3 and I'm new to it. Please help me. I'm trying to develop a Job Portal web app as a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it. In my validateAction class file

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("username", val.getUsername());
```

After that on every JSP page i wrote

```
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.username}">
            // all the codes goes here
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <h1>Please Login First.</h1>
        </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And in the master page I included

```
<body onload="window.history.forward(1);">
```

so even when the user clicks the back button the browser won't load the last cached page.

and when the user clicks the logout button, I call my invalidateAction class file

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.removeAttribute("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in the session attribute `"username"` should not be `null`. Check that `val.getUsername()` returns a not `null` value. Then keep this variable *final*, i.e. don't allow to set this value twice. Then in the JSP you could check that variable with JSTL.

```
<c:if test="${username != null}">
  User name is ${username} 
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <s:set name="personName" value="person.name" scope="session" />
```